# How to invoke java method from javascript of .vm file

Tags: java, javascript

I want to call java method with parameter form `.vm` file can you please give me a simple example for it.

```
mail.vm

<HTML>
<head>
  <script >
    function functionUpdate(val){
    alert(val);
    alert(getElementById(val).value);  
    //now here i wanna call java method from my java class with 'val' as parameter                          
    }
  </script>
</head>

<BODY>
<br>
<span style='font-family:Arial; font-size:13px;'>
  <p>Dear User,
  <p>Please Rate the Module with your experience
  <form  name="ratings" >
  <input id="$rate" name="$rate" value="1" type="submit" onclick="functionUpdate('$rate');">
</span>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

thank you

Comment: //now here i wanna call java method to my java class with 'val' as parameter

Comment: Make ajax call using JQuery or using other javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript run at client side and java code runs at server side.

so you cannot directly call java method in javascript function.

although you can use ajax call using get or post method to call some servlet, and do call your methods.